# unknown database in jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse, jdbc

I am using JDBC and new to it. but I keep getting this runtime exception:

```
   connecting to psysical database...
   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'kholofelodb'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:943)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4113)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1308)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2336)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
at com.psybergate.database.SimbleCode.main(SimbleCode.java:22)
```

***Here is the gave code***

```
try {
            String connectionURL =      "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kholofelodb";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            System.out.println("connecting to psysical database...");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, USER,
                    PASS);

            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Connection has been made");

            Scanner keyBoardScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter table name:");
            String tableName = keyBoardScanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Creating table...");
            statement.executeQuery("create table " + tableName
                    + " (name , age ,salary)");
            System.out.println("Table successfully created");
            System.out.println("Inserting data into the table ...");
            statement.executeUpdate("insert into " + tableName
                    + "values (kholofelo , 21 , 9969696)");
        }
```

how do I get this code to work? I am only a beginner with JDBC....

for the above code;
     PASS = "passowrd", USER = "root"

I had a problem with port which it was fixed through this site

thanks a lot

Comment: What's the name of your database?

Comment: it tells you that it can't find `kholofelodb` in MySQL

Comment: Have you verified that the MySQL server is running on your local machine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

please check in mysql database whether the database name '**kholofedb**' is existed or not

i think you haven't created

please check it once if no create it and its related tables also

Answer (score 15):

Log in to the mysql server,

```
$ mysql -u <username> -p<password>
```

List all the databases,

```
mysql> show databases;
```

Check whether your DB name is there,

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| kholofelodb        |
| mysql              |
| phpmyadmin         |
+--------------------+
```

**Please note: database names are case sensitive.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Make sure to not miss the semicolon in the command of listing the databases.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and found that the cause of it was:
**The name of the database here is CASE SENSITIVE!**
So, I was trying to connect using a database name like "test2", but the database name actually was "Test2".

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when server is not able to find the database. This can be due to a wrong port given in the database URL, for example

```
String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/database_name"
```

So check this port number (3307 in the above case) with the port mentioned in the Xampp controler (go to Xampp controller and then configuration of MySql).

Comment: Well formatted answers get more attention on Stack-overflow. I suggest you format any code fragments so they stand out from normal text. More information here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the fault lies with the name of your database. MySQL is the database engine, but within MySQL you can have a number of databases with their own tables. Once you get the database name correct, you may find that the problem will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your database names only. First create on database in mysql* create database connection .Concentrate on these areas : 
database name : 
URL: mention database name properly
that database name should be reflects database in mysql*

Answer (score 0):

yeah this case arrived to me also and actually my database name was correct but the problem is in my port number I was using WAMPP server whose port number is 3308 and i wasted my time by using 3306 so u can check that are u using any other app then first it is recommended to check the port value of it...........

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and its actually because they tell you to use SQLWorkbench....which is a nice set up but when you do dev things like this sometimes your work on that GUI won't actually save to the mySQL, I don't know why that happens. Workbench is a nice thing to have. I am tediously doing it step by step through this website:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-getting-started/en/ ...its old school...but its working, I just threw away my workbench LOL-

Maybe there is a misstep in how I set up workbench? I don't know but I think I am just going to stick to the old school set up-

Answer (score 0):

You've probably not created a database or the name of it is not "kholofelodb". If you haven't created one, do it. If you have but you're not sure about it's name, on command prompt type C:\ *MariaDB location*> cd bin, then *mysql -u root -p* and
enter your password. Then type *show databases;* . Your database will show up with the name of it. Mine for instance is called "sys"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**FIX FOR THE NON TERMINAL SAVY**

... here is how I solved this problem for me by using MySql Workbench.

1. I Made sure I knew the name of the database I was trying to connect to by looking in my application.properties file. **My database was called rewards.**

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rewards

2)Then I opened my MySql workbench file which I had named rewards....I thought that was the name of the database but it wasn't!  When I did the "show databases;" command in MySql, "rewards" was not listed. ***I needed to create a new schema called "rewards" within my MySql Workbench file***.

Here's an annotated screen shot of MySql workbench and the commands I used in MySql to see if my database was created yet. If you are a visual person, **LOOK AT THIS IMAGE**
[Creating/Naming the Database Correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ7JI.png)